# Why did Jules and Vincent go to the diner?

Tags: pulp-fiction

Jules and Vincent went through a complicated day, they had a briefcase with some extraordinary content, they were wearing clothes that may have been too <del>show-off</del>  flamboyant - but yet instead of going directly to Marcellus Wallace they stopped at a diner.

This seems to be a risky move, are there reasons for that decision explained in the movie?

Comment: They're heavily armed bad-ass gangsters. Why would anyone even bother them at all? Nobody bothers anyone else at a diner. The robbery was a fluke event. Also, why would those clothes be "too show-off"? At worst they look like tourists.

Comment: Also, them getting breakfast probably was inspired by Winston Wolf going to breakfast. Let's not forget this was preceded by the whole talk about the difference in burgers in France, and them interrupting the "kids" at breakfast.

Comment: @BCdotWEB: do you really imagine people who transport money, heavily armed, to stop at a restaurant on their way to the final destination of the money?

Comment: There is no indication what is in the briefcase **ever**. It gets described at Marcellus's "dirty laundry" but we never see what is in the case.

Comment: @Paulie_D: yes, I know. The money analogy was for people that transport something valuable and would stop for breakfast on their way (money transporters for instance).

Comment: @WoJ They're gangsters, not employees.

Comment: @WoJ Vincent also goes the bathroom and leaves his uzi on the counter in another room - while breaking and entering someone else's house no less. There was also a major plot point about how he left the safety off on his handgun.  These guys are not professional, security-minded experts.

Comment: @Steve-O: I do not think that it is his uzi, rather Marcellus' (who left to get coffee)

Comment: @WoJ Can you edit this question?  I have no idea what "show-off" means, given a good understanding of this movie.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger: (sorry, not a native speaker, struggling with choosing the proper words in English). "Flamboyant" will probably be better.

Comment: They were dressed no differently than a couple of kids in the summer.  As Jimmy put it, they looked like 'a couple of dorks'.  Does a bright t-shirt make for a flamboyant statement?  Vincent had a white t-shirt.  Where I am from that is about the least flamboyant one could dress.

Comment: During that scene, Jules & Vincent look pretty much like I do every time I eat in a diner. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### They wanted breakfast

It's a simple as that.

After they dump the body with Mr Wolf's help he takes Racquel out for breakfast which obviously puts the idea in Vincent's mind and he suggests breakfast to Jules.

Now granted they are dressed a little casually but they aren't at any substantial risk. No one knows they have the briefcase and they are more than capable of taking care of themselves as they prove.

Comment: *and he suggests breakfast to Jules* → thanks, I missed that part.

Comment: They also had a lot to talk about.